# Dependent Object Type Check Javascript Seems Redundant

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, typeof

Is there a better way of doing this?

If I do this:

```
    if(typeof someObject[bar][foo] == "function"){
        // Do something
    }
```

I get a `someObject[bar][foo] is not an object` error which it's referring to `someObject[bar]` if `bar` does not exist. This means that the code assumes you know that `someObj[bar]` is defined. So my solution was was this:

```
if(typeof someObj[bar] === "object"){
      if(typeof someObject[bar][foo] == "function"){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

If we want to make an effort to reduce code lines and to make good, clean, readable code then looks redundant and ugly. Is there a better way of doing this without having to go through two `if` points? I realize that it's not that big of a deal, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Have you tried `if (someObj.hasOwnProperty(bar)){}`? No strings attached ... ofcourse

Comment: Check this fddle http://jsfiddle.net/4rjjxdzh/

Comment: @PashaB, this is what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/powerphillg5/mobsrut5/ Look at the log.

Comment: @TimVermaelen that is true, but wouldn't you still have to check if the function exists inside that property after? I mean, you would assume that `typeof` would return `"undefined"` if both the method and the property it's supposed to be in don't exist you know?

Comment: @FelipeTadeo then if you want just to reduce the lines do `if ((typeof someObj[bar] === "object") && (typeof someObject[bar][foo] == "function")){}`

Comment: @FelipeTadeo are you looking for something like `if(someObj[bar] && typeof obj[bar][foo] === 'function')`? First condition check that element is not `undefined`,`null`,`0`... and if this is met then check the other part to see if `foo` is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no simple explanation.

In which circumstance/situation do you expect an object to behave conditionally? To give you an example of what I use ... to go advanced ... and in an attempt to go as simple as possible at the same time ...

- Are you looping through a whole set of array like objects?
- Can you trust the object so you already know what to expect?
- object comparison for different data types?

.[I need some editing :s]

```
/**
  * @description Get an object from a list of objects by searching for a key:value pair
  * @param {Object} obj : -literal, json
  * @param {String} val : the value you seek
  * @param {String} key : the key
  * @param {Boolean} isTypeComparison : if set to true, the key and value will be checked against it's type as well
  */
  getObjectProperty: function (obj, val, key, isTypeComparison) {
      var property, o;

      for (property in obj) {
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
              if (typeof obj[property] === 'object') {
                  o = this.getObjectProperty(obj[property], val, key);
                  if (o) {
                      break;
                  }
              } else {
                  // found a property which is not an object
                  if (isTypeComparison) {
                      if (property === key && obj[property] === val) {
                          // we got a match
                          o = obj;
                          break;
                      }
                  } else {
                      if (property == key && obj[property] == val) {
                          // we got a match
                          o = obj;
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      return o || undefined;
  },
```

To add some sort of value to your question, in all these loops above you see a struggle to an expectation. I've used this code to search through an ajax contact list, attached to a list. So you definitely need to write more code to meet depth and trust requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( someObject.bar && someObject.bar.foo && typeof someObject.bar.foo === "function" ){
    ...
}
```

or the same but with the better visibility notation style:

```
if( someObject.bar 
    && someObject.bar.foo 
    && typeof someObject.bar.foo === "function" ){
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you generalize your problem, you're basically asking if you can verify a sort of 'path' in an object as being legitimate.  The way I would do this is with an a function that takes the object and the desired 'path':

```
function has(obj, path){
    var temp = obj;
    var path = path.split('.');
    for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
        if(temp[path[i]])
            temp = temp[path[i]];//path still exists
        else
            return false;//path ends here
    }
    return true;//the whole path could be followed
}
```

This example uses a path passed as 'bar.foo' but you could easily adjust for an array ['bar','foo'] or so that it is a variable amount of arguments passed in.

This would make your example:

```
if(has(someObject, bar + '.' + foo)){
    if(typeof someObject[bar][foo] == "function"){
        // Do something
    }
}
```

While this doesn't reduce this example in specific, if you had a much longer path to search, this could significantly reduce if statements chained together.

You could modify the function so that it returns the value specified by the path should it exist instead of true so that you only deal with one line:

```
function get(obj, path){
    var temp = obj;
    var path = path.split('.');
    for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
        if(temp[path[i]] !== undefined)
            temp = temp[path[i]];//path still exists
        else
            return undefined;//path ends here
    }
    return temp;//the whole path could be followed
}

if(typeof get(someObject, bar + '.' + foo) === 'function'){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: minified version for array as second argument: function get(o,p){for(i=0;i<p.length;i++){if(o[p[i]]!==undefined)o=o[p[i]];else return undefined}return o}